# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, angularjs

When we are accessing data from server using angularjs we are getting a CORSE-Error

Our code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.survey = true;
    $scope.question = false;
        $http.get("http://localhost:8081/NxtLife_Demo/getsurveyall").success(function(data) {
        $scope.surveys = data;
    });
});
```

Controller-code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getsurveyall", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String getSurveyAll() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Set<SurveyRecords> records = new HashSet<SurveyRecords>();
    records.addAll(surveyService.getSurveyAll());
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(records);
}
```

The Error Message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the
>   remote resource at http://localhost:8081/NxtLife_Demo/getsurveyall. (Reason: 
>   CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: What is the url of your app ?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cors

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by making the following change within the web.config file of our WebAPI :
Reference URL:[enabling cross-origin resource sharing on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7)

```
   <system.webServer>
           <httpProtocol>
               <customHeaders>
                   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
               </customHeaders>
           </httpProtocol>
       </system.webServer>
```

Comment: actually i have web.xml file in spring hibernate based application

Comment: Refer this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I recently aked a question in which I received a detailed info about CORS issues in Spring, read Nikolay answer :
[Angular JS and Spring MVC @RestController - POST status 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238222/angular-js-and-spring-mvc-restcontroller-post-status-0)